# Logo do Layout quebra ao sair do Index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Olá, a minha logo quebra após sair do index, seja qual for a view(edit,delet, etc.), ele quebra, no Index fica normal, gostaria de saber como arrumar isso, a seguir o erro e o código.
Estou utilizando asp.net core MVC e Razor Pages para Views.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src=" images/imagem-logo-9A7444CA59-seeklogo.com_preview_rev_1.png" width=60 height=40 /></a>
                        <div class="navbar-nav">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Items" asp-action="Index">Items <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Fichas" asp-action="">Fichas<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
                            <a class="nav-link " asp-area="" asp-controller="Locations" asp-action="">Usuários<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
                            <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" asp-controller="Loc">Histórico</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a asp-controller="Loc" asp-action="Item" class="dropdown-item">Items</a>
                                    <a asp-controller="Loc" asp-action="Index" class="dropdown-item">Computadores</a>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Altere o caminho da imagem para pegar sempre da raiz

```
<img src="/images/imagem-logo-9A7444CA59-seeklogo.com_preview_rev_1.png" width=60 height=40 />
```

Ou verifique o caminho virtual adequado